# Avoid using global variables when using recursive functions in C

Tags: c, recursion

The code below uses a recursive function called *interp*, but I cannot find a way to avoid using global variables for *iter* and *fxInterpolated*.  The full code listing (that performs N-dimensional linear interpolation) compiles straightforwardly with:

```
gcc NDimensionalInterpolation.c -o NDimensionalInterpolation -Wall -lm
```

The output for the example given is 2.05.  The code works fine but I want to find alternatives for the global variables. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int linearInterpolation(double *, double **, double *, int);
double ** allocateDoubleMatrix(int, int);
double * allocateDoubleVector(int);
void interp(int, int, double *, double *, double *);
double mult(int, double, double *, double *);

/* The objectionable global 
variables that I want to get rid of! */

int iter=0;
double fxInterpolated=0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

 double *fx, **a, *x;
 int dims=2;

 x=allocateDoubleVector(dims);
 a=allocateDoubleMatrix(dims,2);
 fx=allocateDoubleVector(dims*2);

 x[0]=0.25;
 x[1]=0.4;

 a[0][0]=0;
 a[0][1]=1;
 a[1][0]=0;
 a[1][1]=1;

 fx[0]=1;
 fx[1]=3;
 fx[2]=2;
 fx[3]=4;
 linearInterpolation(fx, a, x, dims);
 printf("%f\n",fxInterpolated);

 return (EXIT_SUCCESS);

 } 

 int linearInterpolation(double *fx, double **a, double *x, int dims){

  double *b, *pos;
  int i;

  b=allocateDoubleVector(dims);
  pos=allocateDoubleVector(dims);

  for (i=0; i<dims;i++)
   b[i] = (x[i] - a[i][0]) / (a[i][1] -  a[i][0]);

  interp(0,dims,pos,fx,b); 

  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);

}  

void interp(int j, int dims, double *pos, double *fx, double *b) {

int i;

if (j == dims){
  fxInterpolated+=mult(dims,fx[iter],pos,b);
  iter++;
  return;
}

 for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){
   pos[j]=(double)i; 
   interp(j+1,dims,pos,fx,b);
 }

}

double mult(int dims, double fx, double *pos, double *b){

 int i;
 double val=1.0; 

 for (i = 0; i < dims; i++){
  val *= fabs(1.0-pos[i]-b[i]); 
 } 
 val *= fx;

 printf("mult val= %f fx=%f\n",val, fx);
 return val;

}

double ** allocateDoubleMatrix(int i, int j){

 int k;
 double ** matrix;
 matrix = (double **) calloc(i, sizeof(double *));
 for (k=0; k< i; k++)matrix[k] = allocateDoubleVector(j);
 return matrix;
}

 double * allocateDoubleVector(int i){
  double *vector;
  vector = (double *) calloc(i,sizeof(double));
  return vector;
}
```

Thanks for the comments so far. I want to avoid the use of static. I have removed the global variable and as suggested tried parsing with the *iter* variable. But no joy. In addition I am getting a compile warning: "value computed is not used" with reference to **iter++;* What am I doing wrong?

```
void interp(int j, int dims, double *pos, double *fx, double *b, int *iter) {

int i;

if (j == dims){
fxInterpolated+=mult(dims,fx[*iter],pos,b);
*iter++;
return; 
}

 for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  pos[j]=(double)i; 
  interp(j+1,dims,pos,fx,b,iter);
 }
```

}

Comment: Why can't the two variables not be part of the arguments?

Comment: Do NOT cast `void *` to pointers! See `calloc()` calls in your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two approaches I would consider when looking at this problem:

**Keep the state in a parameter**

You could use one or more variables that you pass to the function (as a pointer, if necessary) to keep the state across function calls.

For instance,

```
int global = 0;
int recursive(int argument) {
  // ... recursive stuff
  return recursive(new_argument);
}
```

could become

```
int recursive(int argument, int *global) {
  // ... recursive stuff
  return recursive(new_argument, global);
}
```

or sometimes even

```
int recursive(int argument, int global) {
  // ... recursive stuff
  return recursive(new_argument, global);
}
```

**Use static variables**

You can also declare a variable in a function to be preserved across function calls by using the `static` keyword:

```
int recursive(int argument) {
  static int global = 0;
  // ... recursive stuff
  return recursive(argument);
}
```

Note that because of the `static` keyword, `global = 0` is only set when the program starts, not every time the function is called, as it would be without the keyword. This means that if you alter the value of `global`, it would keep this value the next time the function is called.

This method *can* be used if you only use your recursive function once during your program; if you need to use it multiple times, I recommend that you use the alternative method above.

Comment: Note also that using any kind of global (file scope or `static` in function) defies reentrancy, so the same function cannot be used from multiple thread in parallel..

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use statics and then to reset the variables on the first call, via a flag that I call initialise. That way you can choose to have the variables reset or not.

```
double interp(int j, int dims, double *pos, double *fx, double *b, int initialise) {

 static double fxInterpolated = 0.0;
 static int iter = 0; 
 int i;


 if (initialise){
  fxInterpolated = 0.0;
  iter = 0;
 }

 .....
......
}
```